# Do I need a return ticket to travel to the US on F-1 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, f1-visas

I'm traveling to the US from Norway on F-1 visa. I just received this generic e-mail from the Airline.

> If you are a non-US citizen or resident flying to the US, you must be
> able to provide proof of a return flight to US Immigrations upon
> arrival. Failure to do so may mean that you are denied entry into the
> US.

I have purchased one way ticket, because I plan to return after one year and unsure about the dates, and I'm worried after reading this email. Do I need to buy a return ticket?

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need a return ticket.

Entry to the US requires a return ticket (with a destination to somewhere other than Canada/Mexico) when you are entering the US under the Visa Waiver Program (ie, using an ESTA). This is obviously not relevant for you as you have a visa.

When entering using a short-term visa, such as a B1/B2 visa a return ticket is recommended, but not required.

When entering using most other visas, including an F-1 visa, a return ticket is NOT required at all.

To some extent, the statement you've quoted does actually cover your situation, in that once you land you will be becoming a US resident (a temporary resident, but still a resident) - so no return ticket is required.  That said, it's still not a correct statement if only because it does not cover B1/B2 visas.

Comment: "resident" has a specific meaning under US immigration law, and F visa holders do not fall into it, but your answer is otherwise correct that no return ticket should be needed here.

Comment: @mlc "residence" is defined in US immigration law as "the place of general abode; the place of general abode of a person means his principal, actual dwelling place in fact, without regard to intent."  It's perfectly possible that an F visa holder could be a resident of the US under this definition.

Comment: @mlc They may not be a "permanent resident", but they are still a "resident". Speaking from personal experience as someone that lived in the US for >10 years on a non-immigrant visa.